# WIndows server 2019 Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value

Tags: windows, iis, websocket, server, arr

I am using Windows server 2019 with reverse proxy configured with ARR 3 and hosted my project with node.js and socket.io, I am redirecting the website `www.mywebsite.com/project` to internal address `http://192.168.0.190:800`.

When I try to access the website `http://192.168.0.190:800` inside the server socket.io is working but when i try to access the website outside the network using external address i am getting the error

> Error during Web-socket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install Websockets on IIS.

Go to the Server Manager > Manage > Add Roles and Features > Web Server > Application Development > Websockets:

[image]